# Using comma in for loop

Tags: c++

```
template <class _InputIterator, class _OutputIterator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_OutputIterator
__copy(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _OutputIterator __result)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first, (void) ++__result)
        *__result = *__first;
    return __result;
}
```

I have taken the above code from the standard template library, what does the common mean? Is it casting? Similar to initialising multiple statements? But in this case casting

Comment: [Read about the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: Closely related, probably dupe: [Why does std::transform and similar cast the 'for' loop increment to (void)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38357089)

Comment: The [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is for extending an expression... Often, in order to use it, you have to keep them inside parenthesis so that the compiler doesn't confuse it with the comma used to separate elements, parameters, etc. which, in fact, is completely different from the comma operator...

Comment: Thanks, also for the (void)++__result i have read that its for prevention of overloading the , operator. Does this also prevent overloading of = operator on __result? Since if i pass in an object for __result, then inside the class define an overload operator =, __result will be taken as an implicit argument?

Comment: So from what i understand, this expression:
++__first, (void) ++__result

Evaluates ++__first but returns (void)__result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that someone might have created a funky iterator type with an overloaded comma operator:

```
struct my_funky_iterator {
    // various normal iterator operations
    my_funky_iterator operator,(my_funky_iterator) const;
};
```

With that overload, the expression

```
++__first, ++__result
```

increments the two iterators and **then calls** the **overloaded** comma operator on the result. That ought to be harmless, but someone who would overload the comma operator here would also not worry about doing terrible things inside that operator.

So the code adds that cast, to avoid calling a possible overloaded comma operator:

```
++__first, (void)++__result
```

Now the compiler looks for a comma operator that takes `my_funky_iterator` as its first argument and `void` as its second argument. The only way to do that is to convert the first argument to `void` and use the built-in comma operator, as if the expression had been written

```
(void)++__first, (void)++__result
```

When you write your own algorithms it's up to you whether this degree of paranoia is appropriate. (you might like to replace "paranoia" with "caution" in the preceding sentence)

Comment: Thanks, what about assignment operator overload for *__result = *__first;?

Comment: @WarriorJoe -- the **purpose** of the algorithm is to **copy values**, so it does whatever the iterator defines for assignment. The `*`s give you the objects that the iterators point at (or possibly a proxy object), and the assignment copies the value from the right-hand side to the left-hand side. The reason we **don't** want the overloaded comma operator is that that's not part of the specification; it's an implementation detail. The algorithm could be written without the comma by putting the increments inside the loop body, and it shouldn't change behavior depending on how it's written.

Comment: ++__first, ++__result 

Isnt the , operator called on __first taking __result as an argument?
__first.operator,(__result)?

Comment: @WarriorJoe -- no, the operator is applied to the **result** of the sub-expressions, that is, the values returned by the `++` operators.

Comment: so the result of the sub expressions:
This would be ++__first => __first = __first + 1;
Is __first+1; the sub expression?

Comment: (__first+1),operator(__result+1){} ?

Comment: `++__first` is a call to a member function: `__first.operator++()`. Whatever that operator returns is the value of that expression. For many iterators, `__first+1` is not a valid expression -- some iterator types do not support addition, but all iterator types support increment. So `(++__first).operator,(++__result)`.

Comment: Ahh right understood, thank you so much for your help! Voted the answer :)

Comment: A few more questions:
Is it true that if the result of ++__first is not of type my_funky_iterator
The , operator wont be called because the , operator function is defined to take  its own type as an implicit argument and the my_funky_iterator as the 2nd argument?

Comment: Correction: void my_funky_iterator as second argument